# Receiving all parents as a Child

Tags: laravel, relationship

Given those simple tables:

**Parent**

| id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

**Child**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value_x |
| 2 | value_y |
| 3 | value_z |

I would like to be able to get all parents as a relation. There is no pivot table involved in this scenario. Something like this:
[Child#1] -- call relationship parents() --> receive Parent#1 and Parent#2

I think the closest idea to solve this is by using a belongsToMany relationship - but i cannot figure out the exact parameter calls to get it work.

**[Edit]** for a better understanding this example might help: Assuming **Parent** is a document scan. Which is made by the scanner which is the **child**. So a scan can only be done by one scanner. But a scanner can of course scan multiple documents.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: I bet, it's hasMany instead.

Comment: Just to double check, a `Parent` can only have one `Child` and a `Child` can have multiple `Parent`s?

Comment: @Rwd correct. I have added a simple example in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a table with a `*_id` field, the relationship will be `belongsTo` which in turn means the other relationship will be `hasMany` (or `hasOne`).

**NB** This is only when you wanting to relate two table i.e. not via a pivot table and not when it's a polymorphic relationship.

This is the what the relationships will look like:

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public child()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Child::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Child extends Model
{
    public parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Parent::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this works. i am ashamed not having trying this out. wohoo

Answer (score 0):

the DB structure is seems not correct

there should be paren_id in child table

create a parent Eloquent model class

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parent extends Model
{
    public children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
}
```

create a child class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Child extends Model
{
  public function parents()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
   }
}
```

and you can get parent like this

```
$data = Child::with('parents')->get();
```

Comment: Going off the example in the question, the relationships should be the other way around i.e. `Child` -> hasMany -> `Parent` and `Parent` -> belongsTo -> `Child`.

Comment: a column parent_id is not applicable here because a child can be used by multiple parents. (i know it sounds stupid but its how the architecture is set up right now)

Comment: ok then just reverse the methods as said by @Rwd and you will get data